# Voltmeter vs Digital multimeter

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Since the internal resistance of a voltmeter should be as large as possible to prevent loading effect, which meter would have the least effect on a circuit VOM or DMM?
Since the internal resistance of an ammeter should be as small as possible which meter would have the least effect on a circuit VOM or DMM?
I was assuming the VOM for the first and the DMM for the second but I can't really explain why and I'm having trouble fining the answer in my book.

Comment: That depends on details of those devices inside. But the more expensive the device is, the higher internal resistance can be expected. Field effect transistors can measure voltage with no current flowing, but the device is more complicated and some small current will always flow.

Comment: I don't know if they use them anymore, but years ago the voltmeter with the highest input impedance was the vacuum tube voltmeter (VTVM). I built one when I was a kid

Comment: There's no magic formula that has no exceptions. Have to look at the specs of the particular device.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

In a *volt-ohmmeter* (VOM), the device uses some of the voltage or the current it is supposed to be measuring in order to swing the needle of the meter movement, an action which requires a measurable amount of work since the needle has a measurable amount of mass and the return spring (which pulls the needle back to zero after a measurement) has a measurable amount of compliance. This effect is called "loading" and a VOM will always load down the circuit it is connected to by some small amount, and introduce a small amount of inaccuracy.

In the case of a DMM, there is no physical work required to "swing" the meter since it has no moving parts- no mass, no springs, no friction. The *input impedance* of the DMM is therefore very high, meaning it draws no power from the circuit to operate (instead, it has a battery inside which does all the work) and will not load or otherwise perturb the circuit.

The DMM always yields a more accurate result than a VOM.